# Android Browser: Horizontal scrolling

Tags: android, css, mobile

I'm currently developing a mobile stylesheet for a website and I'm experiencing a strange problem I can't explain:

Even though there are no "width" definitions in my stylesheet anymore the Android browser leaves a huge amount of empty space on the right causing scroll bars to appear.

I have no idea what causes this as there are no elements and the width is not explicitely set to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the meta tag to your `<head>`?

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`